# Finding the inverse Laplace transform of two given functions

Tags: laplace-transform

> Find the inverse Laplace transform for the following:
>
> a. $F(s) = \dfrac{{2s - 3}}{{{s^2} - 3s + 2}}$.

I used partial fractions and I ended up getting

$$y(t) = {e^t} + {e^{2t}}.$$

> b. $F(s) = \dfrac{{{e^{ - 2s}}}}{{s - 9}}$.

I ended up getting $e^{9t-9} h(t-2)$ and $0$ being $\neq 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

a). is correct

b.) is incorrect - think about the $t$ term and that being $(t-2)$ in the exponential (you got the Heaviside portion correct, so it is close).

It should be:

$$\displaystyle e^{9 (t-2)} H(t-2)$$

Comment: Oh so it would be e^ (9t-2) h(t-2)...I have that written down lol

Comment: You are my lifesaver. Thank you again

Comment: Oh I forgot my parenthesis. I leave little mistakes out like that. And those are important. Thank you

Comment: @BabakS. thank you, great to see you on! Regards

Comment: Great observations and feedback to the OP! ++++